# unicode-math and amsmath incompatible

Tags: amsmath, fontspec, unicode-math

When I compile the following mwe with xelatex, I am told:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Command \dddot already defined.

--- TeX said ---
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

l.571    \hbox{\normalfont ...}\vss}}}}
```

(That's line 571 of amsmath.sty).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIXGeneral}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Hello, world.

\end{document}
```

Is there a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

That allows compilation, but the braces are minuscule (the first one is supposed to span Ordinarium/Extraordinarium).  Here's the longer example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont {LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setmathfont{STIXGeneral}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{c}
Somnium\\
    proprie\\
    dictum 
\end{tabular}
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \text{Ordinarium}
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Vulgare seu commune\\
        physicum ortum\\
        ex principiis
      \end{tabular}
      \left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Externis\\[3\jot]
        Internis
      \end{tabular}\right.\\[6\jot]
      \text{Proprium aliquibus.}\\
      \text{Præsagiens}
    \end{array}\right.\\[12\jot]
    \text{Extraordinarium}
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        θεῖον diuinum\\
        θεόπεμπτον
        immissum à Deo
      \end{tabular}
      \left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Mediate per\\
        bonos angelos\\[3\jot]
        Immediate
      \end{tabular}\right.\\[6\jot]
      \text{Diabolicum}\\
      \text{Δαιμονιόπεμπτον}
    \end{array}\right.
  \end{array}\right.
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `amsmath` before `unicode-math`. And this one in place of `fontspec` (which will be automatically loaded).

Comment: For reference, see chapter 3 of the `unicode-math` manual.

Comment: That allows compilation, but the braces are minuscule (the first one is supposed to span Ordinarium/Extraordinarium).

Comment: @GeorgePigman: This is because STIXGeneral is not an OpenType Math font, either try XITS Math or the new STIX Math (though the later has some issues, last time I checked).

Comment: XITS Math works, but what is the name of the new STIX Math?   STIXVariants, STIXNonUnicode, and STIXSize*Sym don't work.

Comment: Ah, I found STIXMath-Regular.otf in version 1.1.0 of the STIX fonts.  The braces work fine.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I get with the following modifications to your input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont {Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{c}
Somnium\\
    proprie\\
    dictum 
\end{tabular}
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \text{Ordinarium}
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Vulgare seu commune\\
        physicum ortum\\
        ex principiis
      \end{tabular}
      \left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Externis\\[3\jot]
        Internis
      \end{tabular}\right.\\[6\jot]
      \text{Proprium aliquibus.}\\
      \text{Præsagiens}
    \end{array}\right.\\[12\jot]
    \text{Extraordinarium}
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        θεῖον diuinum\\
        θεόπεμπτον
        immissum à Deo
      \end{tabular}
      \left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Mediate per\\
        bonos angelos\\[3\jot]
        Immediate
      \end{tabular}\right.\\[6\jot]
      \text{Diabolicum}\\
      \text{Δαιμονιόπεμπτον}
    \end{array}\right.
  \end{array}\right.
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]